# How can I convert python web application into android .apk

Tags: android, python-3.x, html, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created html5 with Python back-end web application, I am struggling to convert the web application into android web apps. Can any one please help me the easy way to convert to apk file with python application.

Please let me know for any more details.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK does not use Python, only Java, Kotlin and C++. The best solution would be to use the WebView layout and achieve an android UI similar to the website. If you still want to use python I just you visit [this link](https://www.pycon.it/conference/talks/developing-android-apps-completely-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

You may convert your front-end part of application by using Apache Cordova as an example.

For offline work and caching you may try to use Service Workers.
Also the is Quasar Framework, based on vue.js, that provide you ability for converting app into android or ios application, or electron etc.